# Subview of UITabBarController when rotating is underneath

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller, rotation

I'm adding a notification/alert type view to the tabbarcontroller which is my apps rootview controller so that I get the automatic rotating goodness.

However, when rotating my alert view ends up underneath the navbar and tabbar.

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/6851931/2012-06-17%2011.08.42.jpg

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/6851931/2012-06-17%2011.08.47.jpg

The two images show what it does when rotating and what it looks like when not rotating. Is there anyway to get the view to always be on top and have the rotation support?

Here is my code for adding the view.

```
[self.customImageView whenTapped:^{

        MA_MobileAppDelegate *appDelegate = (MA_MobileAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

        UAModalPanel *modalPanel = [[MSPicturePreview alloc] initWithFrame:appDelegate.tabBarController.view.bounds withimage:self.customImageView.image];

        [appDelegate.tabBarController.view addSubview:modalPanel];


        [modalPanel showFromPoint:[self.contentView convertPoint:[self.customImageView center] toView:appDelegate.tabBarController.view]];

    } ];
```

Answer (score 1):

You could bring it to front manually, 
when you create the `modalPanel` add a tag to it

```
modalPanel.tag = 111;
```

on your view controller `willRotateToInterfaceOrientation` function do the following

```
- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
    //Get the modalPanel
    UAModalPanel *modalPanel = [appDelegate.tabBarController.view viewWithTag:111];
    //Bring it to front
    [appDelegate.tabBarController.view bringSubviewToFront:modalPanel];
}
```